# What do you call a set of vertices that separates the root from the leaves?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, trees

Suppose we are given a rooted tree $T$, and a set of vertices $M$ that separates the root of $T$ from its leaves. In other words, every path from the root of $T$ to a leaf contains a vertex in $M$. Is there a standard term for such a set $M$?

Comment: If you want to keep the arborial metaphor going, perhaps "complete pruning" would be appropriate.

Comment: If this doesn't have a name yet, I recommend calling it a topping.

Comment: How about "non-leaves"?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork The set $M$ may contain leaves. For example, note that if we choose $M$ to be the set of all leaves, then it indeed satisfies the property that every path from the root to a leaf passes through $M$.

Comment: Define "through."

Comment: The path contains a vertex from $M$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the root node $r$.  If you join each leaf node to a dummy sink node $t$, then $M$ would be an $(r,t)$ [*vertex separator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_separator), also known as *vertex cut* or *separating set*.

Even without the dummy node, $M$ is an $(r,\ell)$ vertex separator for each leaf node $\ell$.

Comment: ? What about honoring $M$ ?!